# Category permission affecting Catalog Search on frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

I enabled **Category permission** from **System->Configuration->Catalog->Category permission**

When I searched for  product on front end, it was showing bunch of products but the toolbar was showing wrong count (i.e. **1 Items(s)**).

When I looked into code I found that, value of "**disable_root_category_filter**" is **true** for search page and for category landing pages, it's value is **false**.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{   
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    // when count returns multiple rows
    if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->distinct(true);
        $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
    } else {
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```